# How do I put an interactable Canvas onto a 3D game object?

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine, 3d

Is it possible to place a UI Canvas onto a 3D object? I'd like to create a cash dispenser machine (for example) with a user interface that can be interacted with. Then there will be keycode locks on doors, touchscreen computers, etc.

How can I display a canvas as a 3D object in the 3D world and still have it interactable? Placing it on a Plane would be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Change `Canvas` **Render Mode** to **World Space** then drag your Camera into the **Event Camera** slot. You will have to find select the `Canvas`, press **F** in Scene View to find it then move it to the place you want it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [World Space UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html). Can place anywhere in scene but make sure use can view it in order to interact.

To learn more, watch this video : https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/30/unity-4-6-new-ui-world-space-canvas/